# Decorators in class methods: compatibility with 'getattr'

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming, decorator, python-decorators

I need to make wrappers for class methods, to be executed before and/or after the call of a specific method.

Here is a minimal example:

```
class MyClass:

    def call(self, name):
        print "Executing function:", name
        getattr(self, name)()

    def my_decorator(some_function):
        def wrapper():
            print("Before we call the function.")
            some_function()
            print("After we call the function.")
            return wrapper

    @my_decorator
    def my_function(self):
        print "My function is called here."


engine = MyClass()
engine.call('my_function')
```

This gives me an error at the line `getattr(self, name)()`:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

If I comment out the decorator before the class method, it works perfectly:

```
class MyClass:

    def call(self, name):
        print "Executing function:", name
        getattr(self, name)()

    def my_decorator(some_function):
        def wrapper():
            print("Before we call the function.")
            some_function()
            print("After we call the function.")
            return wrapper

    # @my_decorator
    def my_function(self):
        print "My function is called here."


engine = MyClass()
engine.call('my_function')
```

The output is:

> Executing function: my_function
>
> My function is called here.

The decorator itself is identical to textbook examples. It looks like something goes wrong at a low level when calling a decorated method in Python with `getattr`.

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `getattr()`. You get the exact same error when you try to call `my_function()` directly:

```
>>> engine.my_function()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

You have 2 problems:

- Your decorator never returns the `wrapper`, so `None` is returned instead. This return value replaces `my_function` and is the direct cause of your error; `MyClass.my_function` is set to `None`:

  ```
  >>> MyClass.my_function is None
  True
  ```
- Your wrapper takes no arguments, including `self`. You'll need this for it to work once you do return it properly.

The first problem is fixed by un-indenting the `return wrapper` line; it is currently part of the `wrapper` function *itself*, and should be part of `my_decorator` instead:

```
def my_decorator(some_function):
    def wrapper(self):
        print("Before we call the function.")
        # some_function is no longer bound, so pass in `self` explicitly
        some_function(self)
        print("After we call the function.")
    # return the replacement function
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question was only partially answered. Here's how to to modify the `wrapper` (as well as `call()`) methods so they accept additional arguments—that will make it work completely (as well as in both Python 2 and 3):

```
class MyClass:

    def call(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Executing function: {!r}".format(name))
        getattr(self, name)(*args, **kwargs)

    def my_decorator(some_function):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Before we call the function.")
            retval = some_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
            print("After we call the function.")
            return retval
        return wrapper

    @my_decorator
    def my_function(self):
        print("My function is called here.")

    del my_decorator  # Not a permanent part of class.


engine = MyClass()
engine.call('my_function')
```

Output:

```
Executing function: 'my_function'
Before we call the function.
My function is called here.
After we call the function.
```